# Generating Flow Diagrams from Java EE Code

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin

I have a webservice built on Java EE framework (using spring / hibernate / dozer / weblogic webservices api etc). Is it possible to generate flow diagrams for each of the operation to understand as-is behavior? Is there any tool in the market that supports this?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem you are tying to solve. What operations are you trying to obtain flow diagrams of? Are you troubleshooting or trying to analyze?

Comment: I am trying to reverse engineer the code and generate sequence diagrams our of it. It is to understand the existing functionality to help me debug issues and help in understanding the flow for new enhancements.